# Object iteration and throwing exceptions in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Just started with nodejs, from a Python world. Object iteration is not seeming as intuitive as in Python. I have a complex dictionary object and am having two challenges with it :

1. I want to throw an exception and bail if at any point in the processing I don't find the required key (instead of allowing nodejs to add 'undefined'). Is there a way to do this without bunch of ifs. e.g

   ```
   path = dict.url.path  //if url or path are not present, throw exception
   //more nested dict/array looping
   ```
2. Whats the best way for clean nested looping ? I have bunch of arrays as values on dictionary keys and the looping is going quite deep. e.g

   ```
   dict['values'].forEach(value => {
     value['items'].forEach(item => {
      ...
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: This should be better splitted into 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
path = dict && dict.url && dict.url.path
```

It is called a 'guard' operator.(AKA 'and' operator) If one of them is falsy value. path will also be falsy value such as undefined or null

2. You can use it like that. You can reduce the length of code by some tricks, but it will harm readability.

If you worry indentation goes too deep, remember

```
value => {
  value['items'].forEach(item => {
   ...
  });
}
```

above is a function and you can make it a variable.

Edit: If you wanna throw an exception for question no.1

```
try {
  path = dict.url.path;
  if (!path) {
    throw new Error('no path');
  }
  // some other codes
} catch (err) {
  console.error('dict or url is undefined!', err);
}
```

Comment: The first question is about the opposite "I **want to throw an exception** and bail if at any point in the processing I don't find the required key"

Comment: No problem. But I don't see how would your code throw if `dict.url` has no `path` w/o ifs.

Comment: thanks , that certainly helps. But try / catch works for internal keys. if last key is undefined(eg path) it goes through.

Comment: @LazyGetter you have to manually handle it. I've updated my answer

Comment: @ZeroCho You don't with Proxies.

Comment: @ZeroCho . yeah seems like no way around it.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of the first part of your question. Provided that you are using node v8+ you could use `Proxy` to accomplish this

```js
const strictAccess = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (!Reflect.has(target, property)) {
      throw new Error(`Object doesn't have property ${property}.`)
    }
    const value = Reflect.get(target, property)

    return typeof value === 'object' ? strictAccess(value) : value
  }
})

const dict = strictAccess({
  url: {
    path: 'path value'
  }
})

try {
  dict.missingProperty
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

try {
  dict.url.missingProperty
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

console.log(dict.url.path)
```